# Use Parted Magic with YUMI

Tags: usb-drive, parted-magic

I've tried putting parted magic versions on an flash drive using YUMI but every time I get an missing file error stating:

This application has raised an unexpected error and must abort.
[45] File or directory does not exist.
os.debian.52

The flash drive is working and formatted with FAT32 as verified through gparted. YUMI also works successfully when I put Kali linux on it. As an alternative I tried multibootusb, which successfully puts parted magic on the USB drive but then it apparently doesn't do it correctly because after booting parted magic cannot find the SQFS file and is unable to load the GUI. According to this thread it may be a common problem with creating USB utilities. If there's a more appropriate forum for this just let me know. My OS is Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy in the root directory of the flash drive the folder pmagic that is inside `/multiboot/pmagic 20xx_xx_xx`, and hopefully Yumi will find the .SQFS file. This works for me - `Yumi 2.0.0.6`.

Another way may be to go through the configuration files and tweaking inside them. But I haven't had the time to do it as the first solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used PartedMagic from YUMI. It did not work with earlier versions, I got the same error you did. With latest version of YUMI it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based on the answer by DarkHeart, i managed to get it working.

When dropping into the shell:

First, mount the usb stick

```
mkdir /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

Mount the ubcd image on it:

```
mkdir /mnt/ubcd
mount /mnt/usb/multiboot/ISOS/ubcd538.iso /mnt/ubcd
```

Copy the files (-r for recursively):

```
cd /mnt/ubcd
cp -r pmagic /mnt/usb/
```

Reboot and try again. It says "Looking for pmagic.sqfs" just long enough to make you wonder if you actually succeeded, but for me, this fixed it.